# PerformSelector After delay doesn't run in background mode - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nstimer, nsrunloop

I have a voip application which runs constantly on the background as well.
While I'm in the background I'm calling from the main thread: (to establish network connection in case I diagnose a network lost).

```
[self performSelector :@selector(Reconnect:) withObject:nil afterDelay:60.0];
```

However, the selector is only performed when my app returns to foreground.
Should I do anything in particular to make the selector getting executed while in the background ?

Thanks

**Edit:**

```
-(void) reconectInBackgroundAfterDelay:(NSTimeInterval) dealy
{
    NSLog(@"reconectInBackgroundAfterDelay");
    UIApplication*   app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [self performSelector :@selector(Reconnect:) withObject:nil afterDelay:dealy];

        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

I added this code instead, but still the "Reconnect" method is not getting called after the provided delay.
I call the "reconectInBackgroundAfterDelay" method while I'm already in the background.

Any other suggestions ?

**Edit 2**
Found a solution. See below

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The only solution I found so far :

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ 

        NSTimer* t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self  selector:@selector(Reconnect:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];    

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]; 
    });
```

Comment: My application is also voip application. But initially my app shoulld download files from server before register. Is it possible to continue downloading using your solution.

Comment: Here is [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828955/download-files-using-http-request-in-background-in-iphone-above-ios-4-0#comment20777172_14828955] [My question]

Comment: I assume this code replaces the dispatch_async block in your question. Is that correct? Could you post the full code solution just to be clear?

Comment: Additionally, where's the -beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:? Isn't that necessary for running in the background?

Comment: @JoshBrown Yes, this solution is replacement for only dispatch block. Idan already coded his -beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler, see above.

Comment: Great approach! Do you know if it also passes Apple's AppStore Approval Process?

Comment: The NSRunLoop class is generally not considered to be thread-safe and its methods should only be called within the context of the current thread. You should never try to call the methods of an NSRunLoop object running in a different thread, as doing so might cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

Have you put this line in the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` block? Have a look at th section **Completing a Finite-Length Task in the Background** at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html.

Comment: I'm not using a background task, my app is a voip application so it can run constantly in the background, keeping a persistent network connection. Don't see a reason using a background task here, can't see how it would help either.

Comment: VoIP applications don't run constantly in the background. From the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW15): "Rather than keep VoIP applications awake all the time, the system allows them to be suspended and provides facilities for monitoring their sockets for them. When incoming traffic is detected, the system wakes up the VoIP application and returns control of its sockets to it."

Comment: Ok, then let's say I lost my tcp connection in the background, and I want to schedule a selector after 2 minutes to reestablish the connection. If performselectorafterdelay won't do it, how should I achieve it ? obviously background task is not suitable here.

Comment: Unless there's a way to schedule background tasks, which I'm not aware of.

Comment: `performSelectorAfterDelay` will do it (will be executed) if you put it inside the background task block.

Answer (score 1):

I was test it for some time, found that in ios background run when an corebluetooth event coming, if you want to do something delay use NSTimer object，you must be less than 10 seconds, and if more than 10 seconds, the timer will be invalid.

Comment: what is the significance of 10 seconds here? can you please explain it in a logical way?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, let me give an example
see the following code, if DELAY_EVENT_TIME more than 10, this doSomething func will not be called

#define DELAY_EVENT_TIME 8

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:DELAY_EVENT_TIME target:self selector:@selector(doSomething) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)doSomething
{
 NSLog(@"doSomething delay!");
}